# Java, Regex : Adding umlaut and other german characters for first-name

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate first-name sent by user with Regex. I found multiple expressions for first-name, but I also want to add german characters like `äöüß` and french ones `à  À  è  È é  É ù  Ù ì  Ì ò Ò  ñ  Ñ` to it. I tried regex evaluator suggested by SO [here](https://www.regex101.com/), but that didn't help. Wheneever I would make an extra square bracket, it would tell me `Your regular expression does not match the subject string.`. What am I doing wrong?

Current Regex pattern :

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*((\s)))+[A-Z][a-z][äöüß]*$
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do not restrict names that hard. I'd rather suggest a very generic one: `(?U)[\p{L}\p{M}\s'-]+`, use it with `String#matches()`. A bit more complex: `(?U)[\p{L}\p{M}'-]+(?:\s[\p{L}\p{M}'-]+)?`, or `(?U)[\p{L}\p{M}]+(?:[\s'-][\p{L}\p{M}]+)*`, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Can you explain me the regex you posted. Thank you.

Comment: `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter. `\p{M}` - any diacritic. `\s` - whitespace, `'` and `-` are literal single quote and `-`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : One of our crazy developers was trying some ascii art for names. Will this regex be sufficient to stop it?

Comment: Well, it is difficult to tell, [ASCII art](http://chris.com/ascii/) is rather a free from of text. I think one can draw with letters as well. You should come up with some specs then to define the name constraints. However, [it is not good idea to validate human names at all](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Your regex worked. Please post an answer for the same. Thank you. Some of the crazy names he tried : ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)    (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻    ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[It is not a good idea to restrict people's names too much](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), I suggest a rather generic regex:

```
s.matches("(?U)[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s'-]+")
```

This regex will match a string only consisting of 1 or more Unicode letters, diacritics, whitespaces, apostrophes or hyphens.

If you need more restrictive checks, like a whitespace may only appear inside the string and only if not consecutive, use grouping:

```
"(?U)[\\p{L}\\p{M}'-]+(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\p{M}'-]+)*"
```

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how I can add numbers to this? Also, I have never seen such regex, is this some different type?Thank you.

Comment: Number Unicode category class is `\p{N}` (or a more strict, `\p{Nd}`). So, just add this after `\p{M}` and that is all there needs to be done. Another idea: `"(?U)[-\\w\\p{M}\\s'&&[^_]]+"` (where you may remove `&&[^_]` if you also want to allow `_`).

Comment: Thanks, I had added Nd, based upon Intellij suggestions, changed to N. Found an awesome tut on http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html . Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with previous answer from Wiktor.

But to answer why your regex did not work:

You expected a capital letter followed by 0 or more letters and a space and then another word. And that other word is 1 cap. letter, 1 letter and then 0 or more Umlauts. I do not know any name that would fit. All those special characters should be in the same [] as the letters.

Also hyphenated names are not allowed.

So your regex could look more like this:

```
^([A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züäöß]*(\s|-))*[A-ZÜÄÖ][a-züäöß]*$
```